# jQuery plugin not loading in IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I'm using `jQuery` selectbox and it works in all tested browsers except IE.

This is how I'm loading it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#team").selectbox({
            speed: 100
        });
        $("#site").selectbox({
            speed: 100
        });
        $("#info").selectbox({
            speed: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'selectbox'
```

Please help, if you can.

P.S., Here's the contents of the js load order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/globals.js"></script>
```

Comment: check r u load selectbox js?

Comment: yeah it works in firefox, chrome, and opera.

Comment: Post the contents of your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Selectbox works fine in IE. Your problem is elsewhere and not in the code you posted. Can you post HTML please?

Comment: type $.selectbox into your dev console, if it returns undefined then the plugin has not been loaded, if it returns function... then its loaded but it could be some kind of Internet Explorer error judging by SCRIPT438

Comment: Confirmed duplicate, that was me a few days ago.  Still stuck on this same issue.

Comment: It's a conflict with foundation.  By reordering my js loads I was able to get it to work, but now IE is complaining about foundation - same complaint - object does not have property foundation.  I'll update the question with the load order